# What problems can come from a tree with its graft union 5 inches above the soil line?

Tags: trees, containers, apples, grafting

I planted a grafted apple tree in a pot and shortly thereafter realized the graft union is about 5-6 inches above the soil line. My gardening books and online searches recommend the union be no more than 3 inches above the soil line.

Will it harm the tree if I leave it as is, or should I stop being lazy and replant it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are worried about it, put a 6' diameter circle of topsoil mixed with compost around the tree to a depth of about three inches.  I do not recommend replanting as this will set back the tree. My method will actually speed up the maturity. It works especially well if you maintain a 1" mulch of organic matter around the tree. One of my trees has the graft about 6" above ground and it is fine without any protection.

Comment: Do you have to be careful about burying the tree's flare? A common problem with domestic trees is that they get buried at their base. 1" of just mulch is probably okay as the mulch will break down - but it is something to be aware of. Come to think of it, adding a small mulch layer as suggested would be better than townsean's suggestion of replanting (which implies more burial!)

Comment: Come to think of it, I think that's why I initially planted the with its union so far up. I didn't know the term for that was tree flare. Learn something new everyday. :)

Comment: Yes, leave a small ring around the trunk so you don't bury the root flare